# user is not able to post a comment in laravel

Tags: laravel, migration, postman

> Route

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth:api', \App\Http\Middleware\OnlyRegisteredUsers::class]], function(){
    Route::post('commentOnPost','UserController@commentOnPost');
});
```

> Migration
>   after creating this migration i have run php artisan migrate command

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
            $table->string('comment');
            $table->boolean('hide')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

> Controller
>   it is showing error in controller

```
public function commentOnPost(Request $request){
    $userid = $request->user()->id;
    $postid = $request->get('post_id');
    $comment = trim($request->get('comment'));
    //dump($comment);
    $user = User::where(['id'=>$userid, 'hide'=>0])->first();

    $post = DB::table('posts')->where(['id'=>$postid])->first();

    if($user && $post && $comment){
        DB::table('comments')->insert([
            'user_id' => $userid,
            'post_id' => $postid,
            'comment' => $comment,
            'hide' => 0,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]);
        return ['message'=>'ok'];
    }else{
        return abort('403', 'Invalid Request');
    }
}
```

> i am getting an error  SQL exception:SQL Integrity Constraient
>   violation exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
public function commentOnPost(Request $request){
    $userid = $request->user()->id;
    $postid = $request->get('post_id');
    $comment = trim($request->get('comment'));
    //dump($comment);
    $user = User::where(['id'=>$userid, 'hide'=>0])->first();

    $post = DB::table('posts')->where(['id'=>$postid,'hide'=>0])->first();

    if($user && $post && $comment){
        DB::table('comments')->insert([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'post_id' => $post->id,
            'comment' => $comment,
            'hide' => 0,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]);
        return ['message'=>'ok'];
    }else{
        return abort('403', 'Invalid Request');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> i have tested this code at my system ,there is just a small error

```
$post = DB::table('posts')->where(['id'=>$postid])->first();
```

> it should be

```
$post = DB::table('posts')->where(['id'=>$postid,'hide'=>0])->first();
```

Comment: You have forgot to add hide column